# How to set up my web app database to use a postgres db in another machine?

Tags: postgresql, ssh, next.js, prisma

So I'm using prisma with next.js in my web app and I need to provide a database url for my postgres db. However the db that I want to reach is in another machine where I have to use ssh tunnel. I'm sorry if I'm a bit all over the place I'm still new with this and I'm still learning. Below is what I need to modify.

```
DATABASE_URL='postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<db-host>:<db-port>/<db-name>'
```

Anyone willing to help/explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to create the tunnel. You can find lots of guides that will show you how to do that, but as an example, I'll paste one way:

```
ssh -L 5432:DBHOST:5432 USER@PROXY -N
```

Replace `DBHOST` with the DB machine name/address, `USER` with the ssh user and `PROXY` with the name/address of the machine that tunnels the connections.

Tools such as AutoSSH could be used in order to handle the tunnel in a more robust way.

Once the tunnel is up, replace `<db-host>` with `localhost` and `<db-port>` with `5432` in the DB url that you posted.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this and update later.